# Can "what" be a relative pronoun?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Context:

> These specialty jobs are integral to the daily well-being of the
> entire population, which lives in near isolation, what feels like
> light years away from a hospital, a department store, and the
> internet.

I understand that *which lives in near isolation* refers to *the entire population*, but which part of the sentence does *what feels like light years away...* refer to? Is it a relative clause, same as *which lives in near isolation*?

How should I paraphrase this sentence?

--
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike *which* (which has the antecedent "the entire population"), *what* does not have an external antecedent in that sentence.

Rather, this is a "fused relative" construction: "what feels like light years away from a hospital" functions like a noun phrase consisting of a nominal head followed by a relative clause: **something** **that** feels like light years away from a hospital. *What* is fairly commonly used in fused relative constructions in standard English, even though *what* is generally not used as a relative pronoun with an external antecedent.

The meaning of the sentence is therefore similar to the following (where just "light years away from a hospital" is used):

> These specialty jobs are integral to the daily well-being of the entire population, which lives in near isolation, light years away from a hospital, a department store, and the internet.

Saying "what feels like light years away from a hospital" makes it clear that it isn't literally light years away.

A shorter sentence that would show the same usage would be "The entire population lives what feels like light years away from a hospital."

Comment: That's the meaning, but it's still very awkward. It would be much more idiomatic if *what feels like* were simply replaced with *seemingly*.

Comment: Is this fused relative construction commonly used in daily communication? Is it awkward only in this sentence or in general usage as well?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Isn't it just "light years" that modifies "away", thus the PP is "light years away from the hospital" functioning as complement of the prep "like" ("x  feels [like light years away from the hospital"].), where the PP is PC of "feels"?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. In, for example, "Alpha Centauris is 4.7 million light years away", we're assuming that the NP "4.7 million light years modifies "away" --  But it is not omissible. To make that work, "4.7m miles" would have to be a complement, not a modifier, of "away". Btw, "like" takes PP complements e.g. "It's just like in the States".